# Estructuras de Datos

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Tengo una duda en la parte de la creación de una estructura de datos de tipo pila y espero me puedan ayudar.

- ¿Porque aquí tengo que volver a indicar que el UltimoValorIngresado es igual al nuevo_nocdo?. Si ya lo indiqué en la línea de código de arriba?
- ¿Que no se supone que nuevo_nocdo es solo un objeto que hace referencia a la clase Nodo?

```
//Método para insertar un nodo en la pila
public void InsertarNodo(int nodo) {

    Nodo nuevo_nocdo = new Nodo(nodo);
    nuevo_nocdo.siguiente = UltimoValorIngresado;

    UltimoValorIngresado = nuevo_nocdo;
    tamano++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por algo que no es tan obvio en Java porque se hace de manera más o menos automática por ti.

Tu clase nodo debe de tener esta forma:

[image: Estructura de nodo]

Siguiente siempre se inicializa en nulo, de manera que puedas crear una lista ligada simple mediante

[image: lista ligada simple de nodos]

El truco que está haciendo tu profe es mantener una variable que referencia siempre al anterior valor que estaba y que lo referencia como el siguiente.

Esto puede parecer algo contradictorio, pero es solo un truquito.

Si en el diagrama anterior cambiamos las etiquetas y pensamos que el nuevo que se agrega no es el siguiente, sino que el que estaba es el siguiente tenemos prácticamente lo mismo pero nuestra lógica es diferente.

[image: ejemplo con un valor]

y al agregar otro sería

[image: ejemplo por inducción]

Como estamos pensando en listas ligadas es que estamos pintando todo en horizontal, pero para simular una pila tal vez nos sea más natural pensar en esto verticalmente, así que me permitiré girar el dibujito.

[image: pila con un elemento]

y al agregar otro elemento obtenemos

[image: pila con dos elementos]

Y así sucesivamente

[image: pila con tres nodos de lista ligada simple]

Creo que así se ve mas claro pero... que tiene todo esto que ver con punteros?

Pues lo que pusimos como nota es realmente un puntero, y Java automáticamente se dedica a detectar las clases a las que nadie referencia para borrarlas y liberar memoria.

Para ello supongamos que del diagrama anterior queremos borrar el nodo 3, tocará hacerlo nulo y al hacerlo nulo, su siguiente también se vuelve nulo, uno se pensaría que con esto bastaría pero no...

[image: mal borrado de nodo 3]

Como nadie referencia al nodo 2 este se borra automáticamente en algún momento, y lo mismo pasa después con el nodo 1.

Para evitar ese problema deberemos hacer álgebra de punteros, pero tranquilo, no de manera implícita ( o como solemos decir a mano ), sino solo poniendo una referencia a lo que no queremos borrar de la siguiente manera:

[image: cambio de puntero]

Y ahora sí, podemos borrar de manera segura ese nodo simplemente haciendo que su siguiente sea `null`, y por ejemplo así podemos imprimirlo y sacarlo de la pila

[image: operación de pop realizada correctamente]

Comment: Solo un apunte: En Java no existe la aritmética de punteros puesto que no existen punteros. Cambiar la referencia de una variable no es hacer aritmética de punteros.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

`UltimoValorIngresado` me imagino que sea la variable que almacena la referencia al top de la pila, ya que en este tipo de estructuras el último valor que se agrega se va hacia el top. Esto se conoce LIFO (Last In, First Out = Último en Entrar, Primero que Salir). Por tal motivo, cuando agregas un nuevo valor tienes que:

1 - Crear un nuevo nodo para almacenar este valor (`Nodo nuevo_nocdo = new Nodo(nodo);`)
2 - Como el nuevo nodo (`nuevo_nocdo`) será el nuevo top ahora (el primer elemento) indicamos que el siguiente a este nuevo primer elemento (el segundo elemento) es el que hasta ahora era el primer elemento (`nuevo_nocdo.siguiente = UltimoValorIngresado;`)
3 - Por último actualizamos la referencia de la variable `UltimoValorIngresado` para que apunte al nuevo primer elemento (nodo) (`UltimoValorIngresado = nuevo_nocdo;`)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda